Trouble Filtering Contacts by Phone Number with Microsoft Graph API
I'm encountering an issue while trying to filter organization contacts by phone number using the Microsoft Graph API. When I execute the following query in Graph Explorer:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/contacts?$filter=phones/any(phone: phone/number eq '+551000')

I receive the error message:

Invalid filter clause: A binary operator with incompatible types was
detected. Found operand types 'microsoft.graph.phone' and 'Edm.String'
for operator kind 'Equal'.

Despite ensuring the syntax of my query is correct, it seems there's a compatibility issue with the data types.
Could someone please advise on how to resolve this error or suggest an alternative approach for filtering contacts by phone number with the Microsoft Graph API?
Any insights or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/contacts?$filter=phones/any(s:s/business  eq '"+phoneNumber+"')
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/contacts?$filter=phones/any(phone: phone/number eq '+551000')


The error is expected as $filter is not supported on phones property. You can refer this MS Doc to check which properties support filtering on organizational contacts endpoint.
Alternatively, register one Entra ID application and grant OrgContact.Read.All permission of Application type as below:

Now, you can make use of below sample C# code that fetches whole set of contacts and filter it locally based on phone number:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var tenantId = "tenantId";
        var clientId = "appId";
        var clientSecret = "secret";
        var phnNumber = "+9191xxxxx"; // Replace with the phone number you are filtering for

        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        };

        var cred = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(cred, scopes);

        try
        {
            var contacts = await graphClient.Contacts.GetAsync();

            var filteredContacts = contacts.Value
                .Where(contact => contact.Phones != null && contact.Phones.Any(phone => phone.Number == phnNumber))
                .ToList();

            foreach (var contact in filteredContacts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Contact Name: {contact.DisplayName}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Contact ID: {contact.Id}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Contact Number: {string.Join(", ", contact.Phones.Where(phone => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(phone.Number)).Select(phone => phone.Number))}");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{exception.GetType().FullName}: {exception.Message}");
        }
    }
}

Response:

